# Kill batch file in such a way that its children are killed too, in Windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I need to start an `exe` from a `cmd` (wrap the exe so I can supply some command-line options). The problem is that just calling the exe from the cmd does not make the wrapping completely transparent: if the .exe hangs, killing the cmd won't kill the exe. I need it to kill the exe too. Can I do that in plain Windows (from XP up), without adding any dependencies?

In Bash you have `exec` which replaces the shell process with the supplied command. This is handy for writing wrapper scripts, making the wrapping process completely transparent. I know Windows lacks `execve()` to make this possible, but I'm only interested in the parent-killing-its-children part.

CLARIFICATION: I'm not looking for ways to kill the exe, I am looking for ways to *wrap* (start) the exe so that killing it using standard ways (eg. Ctrl+C or from task manager) works. For instance, I could create a `lnk` file (Windows shortcut) and get this behavior, but I want to do it from a script (for one, lnks only work with absolute paths, I can't deploy that).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`Taskkill` can be used to match certain criteria. By entering `Taskkill/?` you get the manual and can read up on how to filter using common properties. I assume that all your children share a common portion in their name. You could use taskkill to math the name with wildcards and close all children that matched that name.

---

EDIT (taken from the comments section):
As IInspectable points out you can kill all child processes using the `/T` flag.

---

EDIT starting from a batch you could use `START` ([reference here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491005.aspx)) to launch the exe parallel to the batch and have your abort in the batch.

Edit i wrote and tested this mini example:

```
@echo off
echo starting %1
start %1
echo Any key to kill execution
pause >>  NUL
taskkill /IM %1 /t
```

Comment: No need to filter on filenames. The `/T` parameter is good enough. Full reference: [Taskkill](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491009.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, but I want to be able to kill the batch file with the usual method because I launch it from a code editor (SciTE) and I want to be able to kill it with Ctrl+Break from the editor. That's why a _transparent_ way of wrapping is important to me. If cmd can't do it, I'll make a C wrapper but I want to make sure before I make an entire C toolchain a dependency :)

Comment: Maybe you should ask that question here - it is likely that the problem you solve has been solved already.

Comment: This post may have your answer https://superuser.com/questions/727724/close-programs-from-the-command-line-windows

Answer (score -1):

```
taskkill /F /IM iexplore.exe
```

*`/F` to force kill.*

Which can kill subprocesses
e.g. https://www.windows-commandline.com/taskkill-kill-process/